# Why can't the maven-deploy-plugin resolve my custom system property?

Tags: maven, groovy, maven-3, gmaven-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm using the gmaven-plugin to [set a custom system property](https://gist.github.com/970877/520497a0ec2b44124031719dc4601bf7ed7cf981) in my POM.  This seems to work, as I'm able to successfully echo the property using the maven-antrun-plugin; however, the maven-deploy-plugin seems completely unaware of the property and is unable to resolve it.

Relevant portion of the POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>
                            System.setProperty("nodotsversion", "${env.PATCH_VERSION}".replace('.', ''))
                        </source>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version><!-- 1.2 in central -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="${nodotsversion}" />     
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <repositoryId>artifactory</repositoryId>
                <packaging>sql</packaging>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                <url>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}</url>
                <groupId>com.company.product</groupId>
                <artifactId>patch${nodotsversion}</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <file>${WORKSPACE}/myfile.sql</file>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run this with `mvn clean install deploy:deploy-file`, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
  [0]  'artifactId' with value 'patch${nodotsversion}' does not match a valid id pattern.
```

**Why is the maven-antrun-plugin able to resolve my custom system property, while the maven-deploy-plugin is not?**

Comment: Does `mvn clean deploy` work?

Comment: @Raghuram - No, the only artifact I create with this POM is a .sql file, and Maven has no sql packaging type.  This means I can't run deploy:deploy and have to run deploy:deploy-file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I believe that the `${...}` placeholder syntax can only resolve project properties. I believe the system properties are added to the project properties at a point in the build, which is why system properties are available in this way, but a system property added later in the build won't be available. You should [add the property to the project properties](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code#ExecutingGroovyCode-CustomProperties) instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is good information.  What worked for me was to set a project property with         `project.properties.setProperty('nodotsversion',"${env.PATCH_VERSION}".replace('.', ''))`.  I can then reference the property with `${nodotsversion}` in my POM.  Note that prefixing it with "project", e.g. `${project.nodotsversion}` will NOT work.

Comment: When the second mojo is being configured, `project.getProperties().get("myprop")` is `null`, even though the `gmaven` mojo setting `myprop` had already run. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is related, but I recently figured out a problem I was having using the `${...}` syntax and the gmaven-plugin. In my plugin I was generating a finalName for the build. This part of the pom looks like:

```
<build>
   <finalName>${my.final.name}</finalName>
```

Then, in the maven `<source>` section I had something like:

```
def myvar = "prefix${someothervar}suffix"
project.properties['my.final.name'] = myvar
```

The pom was for a war. When I ran maven, the output was always:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project myservice: The parameters 'warName' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

After much head scratching I finally figured out how to solve the problem. `myvar` needed to be declared as a **String**!

```
String myvar = "prefix${someothervar}suffix"
project.properties['my.final.name'] = myvar
```